# How do I display input tag and sub checklists for each checklist in json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a set of questions and sub questions respectively. Each question and sub question has a code.
**Checklists** are questions . **Sub checklists**  are sub questions .       Example :-

**Code  Question**
**4.1**   Question 1
   **4.1.1** Sub question 1

**5.1**   Question 2
   **5.1.1** Sub question 1
   **5.1.2** Sub question 2

There are checkboxes next to each question . When i click on them , then the sub questions should display .

My problem here is that : The sub questions of all the question are getting displayed under first question itself .

Here is my code :

```
var json = $.parseJSON(master_checklists);

        var count_checklists = Object.keys(json).length;
        //console.log("No of checklists:"+count_checklists);
            var flag;
            var data1='';

        $(json).each(function(i,val_masterChecklist)
        {

            data = ++count + ') ' ;
            data += val_masterChecklist['code'] + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'
            data += val_masterChecklist['checklist'] + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'


            db.transaction(function (tx) 
            {   
                tx.executeSql('SELECT flag FROM checklists WHERE code ="'+val_masterChecklist['code']+'"', [], function (tx, results)
                {
                    flag = results.rows.item(0).flag;

                    if(flag == 0)
                    {
                        data = '<input type="checkbox" onclick="all_toggle_flag('+val_masterChecklist['code']+',1)">'+'<br>';
                        $("#all_checklists").append(data);
                    }

                    else if (flag == 1 || flag == 2)
                    {

                        data = '<input type="checkbox" onclick="all_toggle_flag('+val_masterChecklist['code']+',0)" checked>'+'<br>';
                        $("#all_checklists").append(data);
                        var checklistcode = chcode_from_schcode(val_masterChecklist['schcode'])

                        if(val_masterChecklist['code']==checklistcode)
                        {

                            data1 = '&nbsp;'+'&nbsp;'+'&nbsp;'
                            data1 += ++count_subchecklist + ') ' ;

                            data1 += val_masterChecklist['subchecklist'];

                            fetch_input_type(val_masterChecklist['data_type'],val_masterChecklist['schcode'],val_masterChecklist['code']);

                        }


                        $("#all_subchecklists").append(data1);
                    }   
                });

            });

                data += '<div id = "all_subchecklists"></div>'+'<br>'+'<br>'; 
                $("#all_checklists").append(data);          
        });
```

The questions and sub questions are from json .

Do share your ideas to solve this .

Thank you ..

Answer (score 0):

I think you should format or construct your JSON string as `Arrays`.

So you have array of questions(the main questions) and for each item in the array it has array of it's sub-questions as array(again).

How to implement this it's dependent in your programming language, and to parse the JSON in JavaScript i'm sure you 'll find alot of help here

Answer (score 0):

You could use place this in the function that is called when the checkbox is clicked.

```
$(this).closest("tr")
```

instead of

```
$("#all_checklists").append(data);
```

I've also used $(this).closest("tr").find(".classname") to find a repetitive location relative to what was clicked.